# Recent movie involving dimensions and time travel/displacement

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a (relatively) recent movie about a kid whose scientist father is missing or presumed dead.  The kid experiences strange situations (e.g., books from a case fall off).  In the end, it was the father the one that was throwing those books to draw the attention of the kid.  Does anyone know the name of this film?

Comment: [This scene might be familiar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo3N9Brp2CU)

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks!  I watched it with my kids and last night we talked about it, but no one remembered the name.

Comment: Well I'll fix up the answer the user below posted and then you can accept that by pressing the green tick.

Comment: Since it is my first time here, how do I vote for your answer Edlothiad?  The answer below seems to be from another user (Nils Tiebos).

Comment: Hi noblestdr, I've not left an answer as the other user got there before me. I wasn't sure if that was the film and my lack of confidence was my bane in this case. I have touched up the other users answer to make it better, you're welcome to give the vote you would've given to me, to him.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is definitely [Interstellar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/) (2014) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film))).

The following scene may be the one you're remembering:

And here is a quick description of the film.

> In the near future around the American Midwest, Cooper an ex-science engineer and pilot, is tied to his farming land with his daughter Murph and son Tom. As devastating sandstorms ravage earths crops, the people of Earth realize their life here is coming to an end as food begins to run out. Eventually stumbling upon a NASA base near Cooper's home, he is asked to go on a daring mission with a few other scientists into a wormhole because of Cooper's scientific intellect and ability to pilot aircraft unlike the other crew members. In order to find a new home while Earth decays, Cooper must decide to either stay, or risk never seeing his children again in order to save the human race by finding another habitable planet.

The strange things that are happening are attributed to "Murphy's Ghost"

Comment: What in the world is an "ex-science engineer"?

Comment: @hobbs I believe Edlothiad means someone who used to be a science engineer, but isn't anymore